# Extract one column from tableone

Tags: r

I use the tableone package in r and it is extremely usefull.
I was wandering if someone was able to easily extract one column from it for convenient use.

[image]

Lets say just take column 1 and put it in a data frame that has
"Name","Value","Value in parenthesises" columns.

Thanks

(Kindly ignore the numbers here, they are just for demonstration purposes.)

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do what you seem to want to do you might use `str_extract` from the `stringr` package. It works like this:

If this is the kind of data you have in your columns:

```
data <- c("1234 (567.8)", "4321 (12.34)", "5678 (91.234)")
```

then install the package and call it:

```
install.packages("stringr")
library(stringr)
```

and define regular expressions for what is to go into the column`Value`and what is to go into column `ValueInParentheses`:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Value = str_extract(data, "\\w.*(?=\\()"), 
  ValueInParentheses = str_extract(data, "(?<=\\()\\w.*(?=\\))")
); df
  Value ValueInParenthesis
1 1234               567.8
2 4321               12.34
3 5678              91.234
```